# Fate of the merchant

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

> Steal my infix and expect to earn
> Steal my whole and get exposed
> Steal my prefix and forever burn
> Steal my suffix and silence arose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the word we're looking for here is

> SHELL.

*Steal my infix and expect to earn*

> If you SELL something, you are getting money in return, hopefully enough to make a profit.

*Steal my whole and get exposed*

> Most unfortunate to be lacking your SHELL.

*Steal my prefix and forever burn*

> In HELL, that is.

*Steal my suffix and silence arose*

> Sh!